# Why do we use the term shadow instead of override in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, overriding, terminology, shadowing

I think I know the answer to this before I begin but after a number of searches on Google along these lines I could not find a definitive answer.

This question assumes we are using the class pattern in Ecmascript 6 and beyond.

My initial belief was that method overriding

> in object-oriented programming, is a language feature that allows a
> subclass or child class to provide a specific implementation of a
> method that is already provided by one of its superclasses or parent
> classes.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#:%7E:text=Method%20overriding%2C%20in%20object%2Doriented,its%20superclasses%20or%20parent%20classes.)

Method Shadowing (more than just block scope 'variable shadowing'- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) on the other hand only seemed to make sense in the context of a strongly typed language like C# that would allow you to set an instance of a 'child class' as type 'base class' which would mean that the the instance reverts back to the base classes methods instead of any 'shadowed' methods.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void shadowedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the BaseClass version");
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void shadowedMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the Derived child class");
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass(); // Because BaseClass type is set instead of DerivedClass
        instance.shadowedMethod(); // It prints "This is the BaseClass version"
    }
}
```

[Code adapted from this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1081861/OOP-Difference-between-Shadowing-and-Overriding#:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20major%20difference,derived%20class%20implementation%20which%20is)

So the question is: why do most JS threads and documentation[ECMA Standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/) use override and shadow interchangeably (but tend to favour shadow)? should we not just have used one term to stop confusion? Is there actually a subtle difference in Javascript between overriding and shadowing a method?

Comment: The ECMAScript standard uses "overriding" exclusively in the OOP context and "shadowing" exclusively for scope bindings. They are not used interchangeably.

Comment: Ah I probably need to spend more time reading the standard. I was basing my statement more on "Understanding ECMASCRIPT 6" by Zakas where he says "methods on derived classes always shadow methods of the same name on the base class"

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find clear definitions in the context of Javascript. So this is my best attempt at answering my own question.

It would appear that all methods with the same name in the derived class (as the base class) are 'shadowed methods', and a subset of methods that accept the same parameters (and therefore create the same interface) are also 'overridden' methods because "Overridden members must accept the same data type and number of arguments". ([see this article](http://www.yaldex.com/vb-net-tutorial-2/library.books24x7.com/book/id_5526/viewer.asp@bookid=5526&chunkid=0514464658.htm))

A method on a derived class overrides the parent/base class if it uses the same signature (accepts the same parameters):

```
class BaseClass {
  overriddenMethod(a) {
    return a;
  }
}

class DerivedClass {
  overriddenMethod(a) {
    return 2*a;
  }
}
```

But it is just 'shadowing' if the derived class method accepts different parameters:

```
class BaseClass {
  overriddenMethod(a) {
    return a;
  }
}

class DerivedClass {
  overriddenMethod(a, b) { // This is not overriding because it accepts different parameters.
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

In more detail, it is 'shadowed' because Javascript is a prototypal language, meaning everything is an object (even Class definitions) and so everything is ultimately a variable on an object and is therefore 'variable shadowing' a variable on the outerscope further up the prototype chain.

Comment: "Shadowing" on objects would be referring to *properties* in general, not just to methods. If you have two properties with the same name but different values, the owned property *shadows* the inherited one. The term also implies that you cannot access the inherited property any more from the object - `obj.prop` always will refer to the own property.